# Sub commands using argparse module

Tags: python

With the below code, I am able to execute in the following way

```
python example.py create path /root/bin/.
```

But I don't want to give argument as `create` and `path` instead,

```
python example.py --create --path /root/bin.
```

When I create subparser with --create, it is taking as optional argument and not like a positional argument. How to make it positional argument with leading double minus sign? and i want path should be a subparser of create

My code should execute in the following way

```
python example --create --path /root/bin
```

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='commands')

create_parser = subparsers.add_parser('create', help='Create a directory')

path_subparser = create_parser.add_subparsers()

path_parser = path_subparser.add_parser('path', help='path')

path_parser.add_argument('path', action='store', help='path')
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: `argparse` tends to parse everything beginning with a `-` as an optional argument (technically, you could hack something together using the `prefix_chars` argument to the parser, but in my tests, that didn't really work out well). I'm not sure why you would want to make those arguments positional though - do you just want them to be required to specify?

Comment: if not with the subparsers, can we do it in a different way? i want the arguments passed with `--` only. Is it possible by overriding `__call__()` method by inheriting `argument.Action` class